# Graphics.setFont is slowing down my program

Tags: java, string, graphics, drawstring

`Graphics.setFont` seems to cause a big delay in my `paint()` method:

```
g.setFont(gameOver); 
g.drawString("GAME OVER!", getWidth()/2, getHeight() / 2);
```

`gameOver` is a font class variable(I read that it is more efficient to create a font prior to setting the font instead of creating it on the fly inside my paint method). When I remove `g.setFont(gameOver);` it runs with no perceptible delay between `paint()` being called and the string appearing on the screen. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: So I take it that you are creating the font inside your paint method then?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes it's in paint, sorry. And I think I might, Andrew, thanks.

Comment: @abaratham What platform are you using and what is the font name?

Comment: Please post more of your code (your complete paint method + the font 'gameOver' creation)

Comment: Are you loading the font or just setting?

Comment: The OP has failed to provide an MCVE for more than half a year, so why this bounty? Since blaming `Graphics.setFont` is rather questionable the only answer can be “learn how to use a profiler”.